# Modifying post_type_link hook messing up edit function for a custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks

I'm using Wordpress as a headless CMS. I have several custom post types that are being consumed by a non-Wordpress application via WP's REST API.

On the custom posts, I would like permalinks to the post to point to the appropriate location in the non-Wordpress application to view the data as it is being shown to users. I'm using the `post_type_link` hook for this and it works fine in all instances exception one.

In this instance, I need to look up if a person is associated with a different custom post type. This works fine when generating the View link. That works fine.

However, *Edit* link for the post now takes me to a screen with just the title and description field with data from a different custom post type. The URL for the Edit link is fine, correctly showing the ID the correct post and the correct custom post type.

Here is the code that is causing this behavior in the `post_type_link` hook. Removing this code resolves the issue:

```
function update_post_link( $url, $post ) {
    if ( \people\POST_TYPE == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
      $labId;
      $postId = get_the_ID();
      $query = new \WP_Query( 'post_type=lc_labs' );
      while ( $query->have_posts() ){
        $query->the_post();
        $id = get_the_ID();
        $PIs = get_post_meta($id, 'principal_investigators', true);
        if (is_array($PIs) && in_array($postId, $PIs)) {
          $labId = $id;
        }
      }
      if (isset($labId)) {
        return get_home_url() . '/laboratories/view?id=' . $labId;
      } else {
        return get_home_url() . '/laboratories';
      }
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', '\people\update_post_link', 10, 2 );
```

What's really confusing me is that **this shouldn't matter!** The `post_type_link` hook should only be affecting permalinks, so why is this even affecting the Edit link on these posts?

Comment: How are you creating the edit link? If you’re using the permalink in any way then it’s going to be affected by this code.

Comment: That's the thing. I'm *not* creating the edit link. It is just the edit link on the page listing the custom posts. I'm not understanding why this code would affect the edit link.